# How can I use .Net Core 3.0 image in Google Cloud?

Tags: c#, google-app-engine, asp.net-core, google-cloud-platform

I'm using Google Cloud to host my .Net Core 2.2 application, but I want to update it to 3.0. My `app.yaml` looks like this

```yaml
service: api
runtime: aspnetcore
env: flex
```

I know that I can specify the .Net Core version in `runtime` section. But Google Cloud Container Registry doesn't have .Net Core 3.0. I've checked it [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/customizing-the-dotnet-runtime).

Should I make a custom container then? I have zero experience with `docker`. Maybe there is a ready-to-go container somehow.

I didn't found any roadmap for update .Net Core images in public Container Registry.

@update

## Solution

It's working!

My `dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY MyProject.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore 

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish /app/MyProject.csproj -c Release -o ./out --nologo

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out/ .
EXPOSE 8080
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:8080
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=production
ENV TAPTAKE_SEED=false
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProject.dll"]
```

And my new `app.yaml`

```
service: api
runtime: custom
env: flex
env_variables:
  ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: "production"
  
# Note this manual scaling is only for development
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 4
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

And my `cloudbuild.yaml`:

```
steps:

# Build
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/dotnet'
  args: [ 'publish', '-c', 'Release' ]
  dir: 'MyProject'
 
# Migrations
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/dotnet'
  args: [ 'ef', 'database', 'update' , '--configuration', 'Production']
  dir: 'MyProject'
  env:
    - 'ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=production'

# DEPLOY
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['app','deploy','MyProject/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish/app.yaml', '--verbosity=debug']
timeout: '1200s'
```

Comment: I'm not sure about the exact syntax, but you should be able to reference the image from *any* registry, and in the case of ASP.NET Core, that registry should be `mcr.microsoft.com`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are already using the Flexible environment, one possible solution would be to set the runtime to custom and then use a Dockerfile to specify the image that you would like, which in this case is .Net Core 3.0.

As an example, the app.yaml file can be re-written like such:

```
service: api
runtime: custom
env: flex
```

We could also write the Dockerfile on top of the example given in the official [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/#create-a-dockerfile-for-an-aspnet-core-application)

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetapp.dll"]
```

Again, this is only one of the possible solutions. Google has [an article that describes 4 ways you can deploy a .Net Core application](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/4-ways-you-can-deploy-an-aspnet-core-app-to-gcp). Granted, it is a few years old, but concepts should still apply. As an overview, you can:

- Deploy from Visual Studio directly using the Cloud Tools for Visual Studio extension
- Deploy a Framework Dependent Deployment bundle with "dotnet publish"
- **Deploy to App Engine flexible environment with a custom Dockerfile**
- Deploy to Container Engine with a custom Dockerfile

Comment: That looks promising. Actually I have a setup with Cloud Build and Triggers using `cloudbuild.yaml` and the last step is deploy

Comment: This is the approach I'd recommend as a Googler, too. While we have previously provided .NET Core specific images, the "vanilla" images from Microsoft absolutely should work, and are the best approach to use, at least for now.

Comment: @Morasiu let me know how it went for you.

Comment: Updates on this would be nice. If anybody has any insight!

Comment: @ThorkilVærge Updated ;)