# manifest for gcr.io/google-appengine/aspnetcore:3.1 not found on Google Cloud Publish

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, manifest

**Hi I am getting following error when I try Publish To Google Cloud on Visual Studio**

**My Project is .NET Core 3.1 Web API**

----------------------------- REMOTE BUILD OUTPUT ------------------------------
starting build "95534111-f021-41ff-9b91-04bb18ea92ec"

FETCHSOURCE
Fetching storage object: gs://staging.xxxxxx.appspot.com/us.gcr.io/xxxxxxx/appengine/default.20200320t113344:latest#1584693302503289
Copying gs://staging.xxxxx.appspot.com/us.gcr.io/xxxxxxx/appengine/default.20200320t113344:latest#1584693302503289...

/ [0 files][    0.0 B/ 15.4 MiB]-- [1 files][ 15.4 MiB/ 15.4 MiB]

Operation completed over 1 objects/15.4 MiB.
BUILD
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
Sending build context to Docker daemon  46.32MB

**Step 1/4 : FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/aspnetcore:3.1
manifest for gcr.io/google-appengine/aspnetcore:3.1 not found
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1**

Answer (score 0):

The ERROR says "FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/aspnetcore:3.1 manifest for gcr.io/google-appengine/aspnetcore:3.1 not found"

When I enter the [URL](https://gcr.io/google-appengine/aspnetcore:3.1) in the browser, I got GCP container registry with public aspnetcore. I searched for the 3.1 but I don't see there. But, I see there are others.

Comment: These links maybe help you: [Docker images for ASP.NET Core apps on Google Cloud](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/aspnet-docker)
 and 
[How can I use .Net Core 3.0 image in Google Cloud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58505180/how-can-i-use-net-core-3-0-image-in-google-cloud)